# How can I recreate the following using list comprehensions?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am pretty new to Python, and I have just started to get the hang of list comprehensions. However, I cannot rewrite the following code using them. Any help with that would be appreciated.

```
for i in range(len(table)):
    table[i*2] += " |"
    table.insert(2*i + 1, "-"*(len(table[0])))
```

This is part of a function, which pretty prints a table by adding a "|" to every second line and inserting a full line of "-"s to the following line.

Comment: is `table` itself iterable?

Comment: To clarify what you want, please add an example to your question.  You didn't include a newline with your dashes, so I'm not entirely sure what you want.

Comment: Please also include sample input

Comment: Does the code in your sample run to completion without raising an exception?

Comment: Table itself is iterable.

Comment: The code itself runs without raising any exception and seems to be working as expected.

Comment: The code you are quoting is difficult to understand, at best. It is certainly not code that you would want to emulate. Translating it to a list comprehension will only make it less clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
table = [ "a", "b", "c", "d"]

table[:] = [x for i in table for x in [i + ' |', '-'*(2+len(table[0]))]]

print (table)

# Result:
# ['a |', '---', 'b |', '---', 'c |', '---', 'd |', '---']
```

As a readable alternative to what you've written, try this:

```
newtable = []
for i in table:
    newtable.append(i + ' |')
    newtable.append('-'*len(newtable[0]))
```

Even though it doesn't use a list comprehension, it is probably more immediately understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to just concatenating:

```
In [1]: table = ["foo","bar", "foobar","foob","barf"]

In [2]: 

In [2]: for i in range(len(table)):
   ...:         table[i*2] += " |"
   ...:         table.insert(2*i + 1, "-"*(len(table[0])))
   ...:     

In [3]: print("".join(table))
foo |-----bar |-----foobar |-----foob |-----barf |-----

In [4]: table = ["foo","bar", "foobar","foob","barf"]

In [5]: print("".join([ele + " |-----" for ele in table]))
foo |-----bar |-----foobar |-----foob |-----barf |-----
```

Obviously you would substitute the hard coded `------` to use the length of the table[0] + 2 to account for the 2 extra chars you add with `" |"` in your loop:

```
table = ["foo", "bar", "foobar", "foob", "barf"]

form = " |" + "-" *  (2 +  len(table[0]))
print("".join([ele + form for ele in table]))
```

But if you want a certain format, `str.join` is probably  better fit:

```
   " |{}".format("-" * (2 + len(table[0]))).join(table)
```